# Get the string before the certain character in python

Tags: python

I have the following string. I want to get everything before the character |

```
'abc eff 23 aaa|C:\\WINDOWS|\\Device\\Harddisk\\Parti'
```

My output should be like 'abc eff 23 aaa'

How do i get it.. Please help me with this

Comment: I see you've posted several questions now, you should get used to researching before posting a new question. Here's a [blog post](https://techblog.bozho.net/tips-for-identifying-and-debugging-problems/) from Bozho on how debug problems from your code, notice how asking a question is one of the last steps...

Comment: Yeah i did.. but couldn't able to find the related post before.. i'll go through that "blog post". Thank you @RichieV

Comment: @Jung-suk - for the record, i found the duplicate question by copying your question title into google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
'abc eff 23 aaa|C:\\WINDOWS|\\Device\\Harddisk\\Parti'.split('|')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the built-in 'split' function as such:

```
'abc eff 23 aaa|C:\\WINDOWS|\\Device\\Harddisk\\Parti'.split('|')[0]
```

[Here is the documentation on how it works if you are curious](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods you can use here either use `string.split('|')[0]` or `string[:string.find('|')]` (as a string is an array you can do this as well)